# Inserir imagem no banco de dados SQL SERVER2008 usando o caminho da imagem

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Estou iniciando em C# e estou com dificuldade de inserir em um *picturebox* uma imagem como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tela acima é um cadastro com foto, e o botão procurar imagem funciona, mas não sei como capturar o caminho da imagem para gravar no banco, que é o que quero gravar.

E também, como trazer essa imagem ao consulta o cadastro.

Quanto ao banco de dados, estou com Sql2008.

Comment: tu esta usando Entity Framework?

Comment: WPF ou Windows Forms?

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo enviar a imagem para uma pasta no servidor, e no banco salvar somente o endereço dessa pasta.

*Envio:*

```
if (Arquivo.HasFile)
{
     if (File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../files/" + Arquivo.FileName)))
         Arquivo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../files/" + Arquivo.FileName));

}
```

*Exemplo de endereco salvo no banco:* `~/files/24054_04.doc`

Fica mais leve, menos trabalho e mais prático do que gravar a imagem no banco.

Answer (score 1):

Então, sugiro que você use uma variável em seu formulário para guardar o caminho da imagem, na minha ideia ficaria algo do tip

```
 string caminhoImagem = "";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            caminhoImagem = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            pictureBox1.Image = image;
            pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
            pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
        }
    }
```

Ai então, é só usar o variável `caminhoImage` no seu método de salvar.