# Salvar foto no banco de dados e depois exibí-la

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tenho uma aplicação para cadastro de alunos onde vai ser inserido a foto, quero salvá-la e depois exibí-la, porém tenho um botão salvar onde quero que salve todas as informações inseridas mais a foto como mostrado abaixo:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-SEFSOUP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DISPENSA;Integrated Security=True");
string sql = "INSERT INTO ALUNO(RM_ALUNO,FT_ALUNO,NM_ALUNO,SERIE_ALUNO,DTNASC_ALUNO, PERIODO, CURSO, RG_RESPON_ALUNO_1, NM_RESPON_ALUNO_1, TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_1,RG_RESPON_ALUNO_2, NM_RESPON_ALUNO_2, TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_2, RG_RESPON_ALUNO_3, NM_RESPON_ALUNO_3, TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_3, RG_RESPON_ALUNO_4, NM_RESPON_ALUNO_4, TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_4,RG_RESPON_ALUNO_5, NM_RESPON_ALUNO_5, TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_5) VALUES (@RM_ALUNO,@FT_ALUNO,@NM_ALUNO,@SERIE_ALUNO,@DTNASC_ALUNO,@PERIODO,@CURSO,@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_1,@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_1,@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_1,@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_2,@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_2,@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_2,@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_3,@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_3,@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_3,@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_4,@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_4,@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_4,@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_5,@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_5,@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_5)";


//Cria uma objeto do tipo comando passando como parametro a string sql e a string de conexão
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
//Adicionando o valor das textBox nos parametros do comando
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RM_ALUNO", this.txtRm.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FT_ALUNO", System.Data.SqlDbType.Binary));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NM_ALUNO", this.txtNomeAluno.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SERIE_ALUNO", this.txtSerie.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DTNASC_ALUNO", this.mtbDataNasct.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PERIODO", this.txtPeriodo.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CURSO", this.txtCurso.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_1", this.mtbRG.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_1", this.txtNomeResp.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_1", this.mtbTelResp.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_2", this.mtbRG2.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_2", this.txtNomeResp1.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_2", this.mtbTelResp2.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_3", this.mtbRG3.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_3", this.txtNomeResp2.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_3", this.mtbTelResp3.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_4", this.mtbRG3.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_4", this.txtNomeResp3.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_4", this.mtbTelResp4.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RG_RESPON_ALUNO_5", this.mtbRG5.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NM_RESPON_ALUNO_5", this.txtNomeResp4.Text));
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TEL_RESPON_ALUNO_5", this.mtbTelResp5.Text));
```

Não sei como passar o parâmetro da foto.

E no botão adicionar foto está assim:

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Exibir a Imagem no formulário
    string nomeArquivo = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(nomeArquivo);
    pcbFoto.Image = bmp;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    byte[] foto = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Estou usando SQL Server 2008 e C# no Visual Studio.

Comment: lembrando que quero salvar apenas o caminho da imagem no banco

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse tópico https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43901/7152

Comment: olhei o tópico e utilizei porém está dando erro de conversão implicita e que está me falando que tenho que usar o CONVERT

Comment: Observe que nessa resposta está sendo utilizado o caminho da imagem, que é uma string. Você deve se atentar se está tentando gravar o caminho da imagem, ou a imagem em si.

Comment: gravar o caminho da imagem, no bd está como varbinary, será que é por conta disso??

Comment: Se você quiser gravar apenas o caminho da imagem, então o campo no banco tem que aceitar uma string. Tente alterar para char ou varchar na tabela do banco de dados e faça um teste.

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Tente  alterar o tipo do parâmetro de Binary para Image.

```
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FT_ALUNO", SqlDbType.Image));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim:

```
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NOME_CAMPO_IMAGEM", nomeArquivo));
```

Mas a variável `string nomeArquivo` deve ser declarada de forma global para ser enxergada no momento da gravação no banco. E você precisa ver também se tem um campo string na tabela do banco pra receber esse valor.